# Bot deleting a message that isn't a command in that text channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
if(message.channel.name !== "cmds") return;
        if(message.content !== "!cmd"){
            message.delete();
        }
```

This doesnt delete the messages that aren't `!cmd`. And it doesnt error, please help.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {

    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");  
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    let command = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();

    let commandFile = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));

    if(commandFile) return commandFile.run(bot, message, args, config)

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
});
```

This is my message object.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? It's not clear what the message object contains.

Comment: Does the bot have access to the specified channel? Does the bot have the `Manage Messages` permission?